# Rename a folder with source folder name matched by wildcard ("*")

Tags: python, rename, wildcard

I have a local folder named "abcd-1" and I want to do something like this:

```
import os
os.rename("abcd*", "abcd")
```

I know there's only one such folder so it's a valid operation, but it doesn't look like `os.rename` supports `*`. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) , `os.path.isdir()` function (to determine if it is a directory) , and then os.rename() to rename the actual file.

Example -

```
import glob
import os
import os.path
lst = glob.glob("abcd")
for element in lst:
    if os.path.isdir(element):
        os.rename(element,"abcd")
```

Comment: Thanks. And I thought Python makes automation easy... Might have as well written it in C++.

Comment: Well I think it is still very less amount of code than c++ right?

Comment: About the same if I used Qt or boost framework, if not exactly the same. But you're right in the sense that the standard C++ library doesn't have a filesystem module yet.

Comment: Yea, `glob` and `os` are standard libraries in python.

Answer (score 2):

See [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)

```
>>> import os, glob
>>> for f in glob.glob("abcd*"):
...   os.rename(f, "abcd")
... 
>>>
```

1. Check if there is only one result or use `glob.glob("abcd*")[0]` for first result.
2. Use `os.path.isdir()` to check whether it is a directory

Answer (score 0):

Use the glob module

eg

glob.glob("abcd*")

will return ["abcd-1"]
then you can rename the folder
You should probably use an assert statement to make sure theres only 1 result

Comment: Slight problem: how do I distinguish between files and folders? There are multiple matches, and only 1 is a folder.